# import data into cassandra with copy command

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I am just a week old to C* world. I am uploading data from a csv file approx(23 GB) using the copy command.

I need to get the rowcount of the column family to make sure that the rows are getting inserted successfully. I read of two ways to perform this:

select count(*) from Limit 2000000;
Using the nodestats tool woth cfstas command and check the 'Number of Keys (estimate)' in result
I tried option (1) but I was kept waiting a long time without any results. I then tried option (2). However I find that the Number of Keys(estimate) to be decreasing with time. This is the part of the output of my node tool 
command :

`nodetool --host 54.225.108.245 cfstats`

O/p:

```
Keyspace: cookie_udp_ja_meta
    Read Count: 0
    Read Latency: NaN ms.
    Write Count: 215724
    Write Latency: 1.1088440368248316 ms.
    Pending Tasks: 0
            Column Family: rpt_true_metric
            SSTable count: 7
            Space used (live): 741159354
            Space used (total): 741160083
            Number of Keys (estimate): 896
            Memtable Columns Count: 437886
            Memtable Data Size: 61865984
            Memtable Switch Count: 9
            Read Count: 0
            Read Latency: NaN ms.
            Write Count: 215725
            Write Latency: 1.074 ms.
            Pending Tasks: 0
            Bloom Filter False Positives: 0
            Bloom Filter False Ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom Filter Space Used: 7792
```

The Number of Keys(estimate) was 896 5 minutes before when I ran the command and 1024 3 minutes before that. However I noticed that the 'Write Count: 324654' value for keyspace is increasing.

I am confused if my copy command is importing data correctly as the operation is not complete even after around 30 minutes . Kindly advise..

Comment: You can find what's going on from my blog post: http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=24  The reason why your count goes down is probably due to compaction removing now obsolete SSTables.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I read your blog and accordingly nodetool compactnt.. But now, the number of keys(Estimate) count has decreased even further to 128. SStable count is 1 now. 
But the select count(*) query returns value with limit 10000. I am positive there are more than 10^6 records as the size of data folder has increased by nearly 2 GB..

Comment: What value does select count(*) return?  It looks like you are inserting many columns into the same rows, possibly overwriting the columns.

Comment: I tried Select count(*) with limit upto 20000, but when I tried very limit with large values like 1000000, it gave a timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wait until the load is finished, the alternative ways of getting the row count are described in this external thread: http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/row-count-for-a-given-column-family

In my case the SELECT COUNT(*) cqlsh command would produce a RPC command timeout even after the load has been done. This is because a very expensive operation in Cassandra and it's success basically depends on how robust your machine is and what the RPC timeout value in cassandra.yaml is.

Comment: In my case too it was giving a RPC timeout error. It seems the 'no of Keys(estimate)' gives the appropriate value only after the entire copy operation is completed and the insertions are done. But I am still wondering if the write count value given under Keyspace will give an approx count of the rows, as it seems to be increasing somewhat linearly with time..

Comment: The write count is the number of write operations, so will always go up (until the node is restarted).  If you are writing to rows only once then it will be the number of rows (assuming no timeouts and retries) but otherwise it will be larger.